# Visual Studio - Web Development and Debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm doing some web development and when I push the debug button it starts off with the selected tab and it is really annoying because it will throw errors because those pages are not meant to be ran at first. Is there a way to have visual studio always run a default page first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the page you want to be the start page and select "Set As Start Page:"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Web Application's Properties Window, Web Tab. It has a box where you can enter the URL to load upon starting debugging.

That is; Right-click on the project item in the Solution Explorer, choose 'Properties', then click the Web tab, and select the proper option for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can also right-click on your desired start page and select Set as Start Page.